# JavaFX: if condition forTextField not working properly on ActionEvent?

Tags: java, validation, javafx, textfield

I have a piece of code, a login form in JavaFX. It is just a prototype, and it is basing on a tutorial which hasnt covered a topic like that. I want to add a TextField validation, I did it like this:

```
Button btn = new Button("Login");
HBox hBtn = new HBox(10);
hBtn.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
hBtn.getChildren().add(btn);
grid.add(hBtn, 1, 4);

final Text actiontarget = new Text();
grid.add(actiontarget, 1, 6);

if (userTextField.getText().trim().isEmpty() && !pwField.getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
    btn.setOnAction(event
                -> {
        actiontarget.setFill(Color.FIREBRICK);
        actiontarget.setText("No login provided!");
    });
} else if (pwField.getText().trim().isEmpty() && !userTextField.getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
    btn.setOnAction(event
            -> {
        actiontarget.setFill(Color.FIREBRICK);
        actiontarget.setText("Please provide a password!");
    });
} else if (userTextField.getText().trim().isEmpty() && pwField.getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
    btn.setOnAction(event
            -> {
        actiontarget.setFill(Color.FIREBRICK);
        actiontarget.setText("Please provide login and password!");
    });
} else {
    btn.setOnAction(event
            -> {
        actiontarget.setFill(Color.GREEN);
        actiontarget.setText("Login succesfull");
    });
}
```

The problem is, that this code ALWAYS returning the text from the 3rd condition: `Please provide login and password!`, the input in those fields doesnt matter. I can provide only password, only login, both, or none of the two, the result will be allways the same.

Am I missing something here? Is this a (very) wrong approach? Or am I just tired and should go to sleep?

Cheers!

Comment: Setting a `Button`'s `OnAction` based on an `if-statement` is most likely an incorrect way of handling things. If you want to set the text of `actiontarget`, you need a to put the `if-statement` in a `TextField` `TextProperty` listener. You also need to do away with the `setOnAction`s. Only set the `actontarget` fill and text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `if/else if` is evaluated at the time you create the GUI.

This means the check is done for the values you've initialized the `TextField`s with (or the default values).

Move the check to the event handler to do the checks for the values at the time the button is clicked:

```
...
grid.add(actiontarget, 1, 6);

btn.setOnAction(evt -> {
    String user = userTextField.getText().trim();
    String password = pwField.getText().trim();

    if (!(user.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty())) {
        actiontarget.setFill(Color.GREEN);
        actiontarget.setText("Login succesfull");
    } else {
        actiontarget.setFill(Color.FIREBRICK);
        if (user.isEmpty()) {
            actiontarget.setText(password.isEmpty() ? "Please provide login and password!" : "No login provided!");
        } else {
            actiontarget.setText("Please provide a password!");
        }
    }
});
```